# Wordpress remove from admin bar menu

Tags: wordpress, admin

I tried to remove User right section but with no luck any help ? WP version 3.8
This code not working ...

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_user_account_menu' );
function remove_user_account_menu() {
    remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu', 0 );
    remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_account_item', 7 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'so27304117_before_admin_bar_render' ); 
function so27304117_before_admin_bar_render()
{
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account');
}
```

Dive into the [admin toolbar API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render).

Comment: Thanks! To remove the "about wordpress" links, use ``$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo')``